# Implementing Instructive Motion For ScrollView To Show a Text Preview

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation

Recently, I started to watch 'Android Material Design' video course on *developer.android.com*
In lesson 4 *Meaningful Motion* there is a video called *Implementing Instructive Motion*. I tried to achieve the same output as it is shown below:
[image]

Here is what I have done so far:

In MainActivity.java:

```
    public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
        super.onEnterAnimationComplete();
Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView,"scrollY",300).setDuration(400);
        animator.start();
}
```

In activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:text="@string/sample_big_text"/>

</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

My question is why the output is different?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set a long enough string to the TextView.

Second, add `android:clipToPadding="false"` to the ScrollView.

(Optional) In the ScrollView, add a white background LinearLayout that contains the TextView.

Comment: First off all, thank you for trying to answer. There was some improvements in the result output , but I did not understand the part that you mentioned 'LinearLayout' because there was no LinearLayout in the presented XML code. I added white background to text box and the result was acceptable(I also implemented your first and second suggestions).Could you please explain why the text does not return to its first place? Surely, I will select this answer as the accepted answer after you complete your answer.

Comment: The reason I add a LinearLayout is to provide background. Adding white background to TextView directly also works. What do you mean that the text doesn't return to its first place? :-)

Comment: I mean the animation does not reset to its initial state, but never mind it I solved it.